# How to save and restore file's created/modified dates?

Tags: linux, filesystems, date-modified

I've copied a bunch of files from one server to the other, and now the files' dates are reset to current.

How to backup files' dates on old server and restore the them on the new one (without re-transferring all files)?

Comment: If you version of `cp` (or `scp`) has the `-p` or the `--preserve` option, you should have used it! Don't forget it next time...

Comment: I used `find ... | cpio ... | mcrypt ... | pv ... | nc -lp 1`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are scripts to save and restore all {c,n,a}times of files and directories:

Save:

```
find / -mount -print0 | perl -ne 'INIT{ $/ = "\0"; use File::stat;} chomp; my $s = stat($_); next unless $s; print $s->ctime . "/" . $s->mtime . "/" . $s->atime ."/$_\0"; ' > dates.dat
```

Restore:

```
cat dates.dat |  perl -ne 'INIT{ $/ = "\0";} chomp; m!^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)!s or next; my ($ct, $mt, $at, $f) = ($1, $2, $3, $4); utime $at, $mt, $f;'
```

It does not [set ctime (inote-change time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537291/setting-creation-or-change-timestamps) although.

Answer (score 6):

I have a Python script for doing this at https://github.com/robertknight/mandrawer/blob/master/save-file-attrs.py

On the original server run:

`save-file-attrs.py save
scp .saved-file-attrs <user>@<dest-server>:<path>`

On the destination server run:

`cd <path>
save-file-attrs.py restore`

This will restore the file attributes.

Answer (score 3):

If file names are not too weird, and I only need to restore mtime, I use this quick & dirty solution:

```
find . -type f -exec stat -c 'touch --no-create -d "%y" "%n"' {} \;
```

This creates a script on the source, and that script can be run on the destination to restore the mtime timestamps.

Comment: A probably faster alternative is `find . -type f -printf 'touch --no-create -d "%t" "%p"\n'` because it doesn't fork. But it still needs some improvement (stable time format)

Comment: I've been using `find . -type f -exec stat -c 'touch --no-create -d @%Y "%n"' {} \; >restore-timestamps` (timestamps instead of local date representation).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stat` to get the dates on the source and `touch` to modify them on the target.

Comment: How to do it automatically for a bunch of files (including ones with special names)? I don't want to stat and touch each file manually.

Comment: You'd have to use a script. I'd do something with find, piped into a while statement, then parsing the output of stat for each file and applying with touch to the source. The actual implementation will depend on the particular file structure involved.

Comment: OK, implementing the script myself (I thought there should be a tool fo this or someone already having such script).